# Factory Pattern, Property 'findByEmail' is missing in type 'IBaseDao' but required in type 'IUserDao'

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I am trying to using the Factory Pattern to create DAO. Here is my code:

```js
interface IBaseDao {
  findOne(): Promise<any>;
}

abstract class BaseDao implements IBaseDao {
  public async findOne() {}
}

interface IUserDao extends IBaseDao {
  findByEmail(email: string): Promise<any>;
}

class UserDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements IUserDao {
  public async findByEmail(email: string) {}
}

interface IPostDao extends IBaseDao {
  findByTitle(title: string): Promise<any>;
}
class PostDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements IPostDao {
  public async findByTitle(title: string) {}
}

class DaoFactory {
  public static create(daoName: string): IBaseDao {
    switch (daoName) {
      case 'user':
        return new UserDaoImpl();
      case 'post':
        return new PostDaoImpl();
      default:
        throw new Error(`no DAO for daoName = ${daoName}`);
    }
  }
}


const userDao: IUserDao = DaoFactory.create('user');
userDao.findByEmail();
```

But got this error:

> Property 'findByEmail' is missing in type 'IBaseDao' but required in type 'IUserDao'.ts(2741)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to infer a type at compile-time from a runtime value (like your 'daoName' string) - the compiler doesn't know what concrete type the function will return.

You'll need to implement separate methods for constructing your different object types (e.g. createUser(), createPost()), which is much clearer and easier to understand anyway.